# How to restrict embedding of youtube videos?

Tags: youtube

[The official support page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6301625?hl=en) provides some steps to solve the task. The thing is, the section *Overview* which is said to be in *Settings* is missing! Can't say anything but that the support page is misleading. How then can I restrict embedding of youtube videos?

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Go to [studio.youtube.com](https://studio.youtube.com)
- Step 2: Go to Content and then Details for the specific video you wish to restrict the embedding
  [image]
- Step 3: Then Scroll down the page, Click on `Show More`.
- Step 4: Just in the bottom, you will see an option to unselect the `Embedding` option
  [image]